# C++ compiles file in a different place

Tags: c++

I am programming C++ files and they are being compiled in a different path rather than the relative. I am using sublime text 3 and mingw to work on c++. My current build code is:

{
    "cmd": ["C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-g++.exe", "-static", "-Wall", "-time", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name.exe", "&&", "start", "$file_base_name"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "encoding": "latin1"
}

When I compile my program, lets say on my desktop the .cpp file is, it puts the exe in a folder on my desktop for example called "C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder" instead of "C\Users\Desktop".

So basically, when I compile example.cpp in sublime text with the location of example.cpp on my desktop, its puts the file in a random folder on my desktop! Its opens a cmd window in that folder, then only runs my program if I type "example" (name of the program) in the console.

Comment: does `${project_path:${folder}}` bear any relation to a folder being named `folder` perhaps?

Comment: That was just and example, and I don't think it would affect it anyway. Thanks though, Its a weird problem lol.

Comment: If you fire up command prompt, and run g++ manually, does it behave the same? I.e., is it g++ or sublime that's the problem?

Comment: `${project_path:${folder}}` should give you the directory the project is in if one is open. Otherwise it will give you the first folder on the sidebar. Could that be what's happening?

Comment: The project is located in "C:\Users\NarrowGlint\Documents\C++ Projects\Beginner\Getting User Input.cpp". When I run the program in sublime, it opens up a external cmd window, then it says the path (at the left side of a cmd screen) is "C:\Users\NarrowGlint\Desktop\Program Uploader" which is a completely different unrelated path! Also, I can type g++ in console it is added to my PATH

Comment: I also just tryed moving the random Program Uploader folder to a different folder on my desktop, and now I am getting a completely different random path in cmd when I build the C++ file: "C:\Users\NarrowGlint\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Floobits" Just random paths, I am confused!